# ClassNotFoundException when submitting yamr job to remote cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, docker

I have a pseudo-distributed hadoop cluster, running as a docker container

```
docker run -d  -p 50070:50070 -p 9000:9000 -p 8032:8032 -p 8088:8088 --name had00p sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.6.0 /etc/bootstrap.sh -d
```

Its configuration here: https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-hadoop-ubuntu/

I can successfully deal with hdfs, access ui, but stuck with submission of job from java, i got

> ClassNotFoundException: Class com.github.mikhailerofeev.hadoop.Script$MyMapper not found

Here's the sample code:

```
  @Override
  public Configuration getConf() {
    String host = BOOT_TO_DOCKER_IP;
    int nameNodeHdfsPort = 9000;
    int yarnPort = 8032;
    String yarnAddr = host + ":" + yarnPort;
    String hdfsAddr = "hdfs://" + host + ":" + nameNodeHdfsPort + "/";

    Configuration configutation = new Configuration();
    configutation.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", yarnAddr);
    configutation.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
    configutation.set("fs.default.name", hdfsAddr);
    return configutation;
  }


  private void simpleMr(String inputPath) throws IOException {

    JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), Script.class);
    conf.setJobName("fun");
    conf.setJarByClass(MyMapper.class);
    conf.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, inputPath);
    String tmpMRreturn = "/user/m-erofeev/map-test.data";
    Path returnPath = new Path(tmpMRreturn);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, returnPath);

    AccessUtils.execAsRootUnsafe(() -> {
      FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
      if (fs.exists(returnPath)) {
        fs.delete(returnPath, true);
      }
    });
    AccessUtils.execAsRootUnsafe(() -> {
      RunningJob runningJob = JobClient.runJob(conf);
      runningJob.waitForCompletion();
    });
  }
```

Here is AccessUtils.execAsRootUnsafe -- wrapping around UserGroupInformation, it's work fine with hdfs.

Where am I wrong?

**upd**: I realize, that it should fail because of hadoop use java 7, but me java 8, and planning to check this later. But I expected another fail message in this case...
**upd2** switching to java7 doesn't make difference.

Comment: How are you packaging and running your Jar? Have you tried running the jobs as shown in their testing section https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-hadoop-ubuntu

Comment: @Upio, yes, i tried testing jobs, and just running this job as jar inside container -- all fine :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, i was running script without packaging it to jar (from IDE), so method getJarByClas() doesn't make sense.